# How to allow person can click the button 1 time?

Tags: java, jquery, html

I have this :

```
$('#row').append('<span id="test" onclick=  "parent.avacweb_chat.like_msg(\'' + username.replace(/'/g, "\\'") + '\', this.parentNode) ">Like</span>');
```

Now I want each person can click the **#test** just 1 time . 
Can you use **onclick** in the code to do that ?
Thanks for help

You can login my link :

http://codefm3.forumvi.com/login

nick test : doannamthai
Pass : doannamthai123

Then go to chatbox at the right corner of the forum

Comment: remove the onclick after the person clicked, or disable the button after clicked.

Comment: probably you might have to disable / hide the button on first click.. to avoid second click

Comment: I want it will be removed the button after clicked

Answer (score 1):

Disable the element

```
// To disable 
$('.someElement').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
```

Comment: I want it will be removed the button after clicked

Comment: it wont remove the button , just disabled it

Comment: $('.someElement').remove();

Comment: I tried but not work .The code I gave in forumotion 's chatbox .

Answer (score 0):

```
make a function like this:

function remov(){
   var a = document.getElementById('test');
   a.style.display = 'none';
}   

call this onclick like this:

$('#row').append('<span id="test" onclick=  "parent.avacweb_chat.like_msg(\'' + username.replace(/'/g, "\\'") + '\', this.parentNode);remov(); this.onclick=null;">Like</span>');
```

hope this will help..

Comment: it will make function to be called once on click of #test

Comment: you have not mentioned in your question that you want to remove button after click

Comment: Ha I see when I click the button It removed ^-^ but 1~2 second It appear again =.=

Comment: Oh if I change to this  $('#row').append('<span id="test" onclick=  "parent.avacweb_chat.like_msg(\'' + username.replace(/'/g, "\\'") + '\', this.parentNode);remove(); this.onclick=null;">Like</span>');  It removed ^-^ but 2 second It appear again

Comment: function remov(){
   var a = document.getElementById('test');
   a.style.display = 'none';
}..i have edited remov function..have you change to new function

Comment: i think webpage refreshes on click of span..is it?

Answer (score 0):

```
var click = 0; 
$('#id').click(function() {  
      if (click === 0) { 
      $(this).remove()
      //First clicked  
       var click = 1;  
    } else {  
      // Hey you already clicked me
    }
});
```

Comment: @user2435289 to remove try this

Comment: @user2435289 you can try it now

Comment: The code I gave in forumotion 's chatbox . The button will appear in each message

Comment: @PSR: i dont find the reason that none of the solution is working for user.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#button').click(function() {  
    $(this).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
});
```

The button is disabled on first click

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
$('#test').click(function() {  
//This is the first click event...write the code to perform the task on first click
//code here..
//and then unbind the click event for current selector
 $('#test').off('click');    
});
```

**[Demo Here](http://jsfiddle.net/NNdY8/)**

**Update**: You can use `$('#test').attr('disabled', 'disabled');` instead of `$('#test').off('click');` to disable the button

Comment: Notice : The code I gave in forumotion 's chatbox . The button will appear in each message

Answer (score 0):

If you want the click handler to be executed only once, you must bind a click handler using one.

```
$("span#test").one("click", function() {
// Handle the click
});
```

This way, clicking the **Like** `span` will trigger the click handler only the first time. Subsequent attempts to click **Like** will have no effect.

Or you can remove the **Like** `span` using

```
$("span#test").remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this as it will help you to remove that onclick event once it is clicked.

```
$(document).on("click", "#test", function(){
    $("#test").removeAttr("onclick");
});
```

or if you want to remove the element from DOM, then use this one :

```
$(document).on("click", "#test", function(){
    $("#test").remove();
});
```